# Benefits of using client-side encryption for user information

Tags: javascript, encryption, web-frontend

Recently, I came across a website where user's phone number was partially visible and you had to click on a link to show the rest. The link had an encrypted id that a *javascript* function used to extract the phone number.

This might look interesting but I can't see the benefits of using something like this, since I can easily call the function and extract the phone number. Is this functionality only useful to prevent search-engines from indexing users' information?

If you're curious this is the function:

```
function d(num){
    num=num.substring(2);
    var c=parseInt(num[0]);
    var n="";
    var i=c+1;
    while(i<num.length)
    {
        n+=num[i];
        c=parseInt(num[i+1]);
        i+=c+1;
        i++;
    }
    return n;
}
```

And the link's id looks like this: `X_31320224932121817272269264130*********`

Comment: I hope you're right, and that's it's just there for obfuscation from bots, or it's a lame attempt at security.  I do something similar with email addresses, where links are made from constituent parts at the time of clicking them, rather than having a blatant `mailto:spam-me-please@your-leisure.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is obfuscation rather than encryption. The fact that it is completely self contained makes that it cannot be anything other than that.

First of all, it doesn't seem to use any explicit key. Integrating a seemingly symmetric key into the data doesn't make it secure - even if it does use a real cipher such as AES.

Second, this seems not to comply with [Kerckhoff's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle), which states that an encryption scheme should be secure even if the scheme is known to an attacker. As anybody can execute the function without a key and get the right result, this clearly voids the principle. You can of course argue that without a key, the scheme will always break this principle.

The only thing I can come up with is protection against (unsophisticated) web-crawlers such as used by search engines.